# Is it Heracles or Herakles?

Tags: greek, hercules

In the question, ["What happened to Theseus after Heracles found him"](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1884/what-happened-to-theseus-after-herakles-found-him/2385#2385) that I answered, someone edited my answer and replaced Heracles with Herakles. I was confused because when I searched up [Heracles](https://www.google.com/search?q=heracles&rlz=1CAHPZP_enUS758US760&oq=heracles&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1765j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on) on the internet, it showed that he was spelled 'Heracles'. After that, I also searched up [Herakles](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1CAHPZP_enUS758US760&q=herakles&oq=herakles&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l4.1541825.1541927.0.1542623.2.2.0.0.0.0.101.101.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.1.100....0.iYCAW5qqQeQ&safe=active&ssui=on) and it showed him being spelled 'Heracles'.

So, can someone please explain to me why @Rodia edited my answer so that Herakles replaced Heracles?

Thank you.

Comment: You should probably take up the part about your answer being edited on [meta]. Most Stack Exchange sites recommend that people _don't_ edit posts just to change, e.g., British to American spelling, and changing between different romanizations of Greek feels like the same thing, to me.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'll think about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Both are correct: if you're not going to call him Ἡρακλῆς, then you need some way of representing his name in the Roman alphabet. Systems for doing this have changes over time.

The letter "k" fell out of use in Latin so, [classically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Greek#Ancient_Greek) the letter kappa (κ) has been transliterated as "c", and this carried through to English.  However, in the [modern standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Greek#Ancient_Greek), designed by the Hellenic Organization for Standardization and adopted internationally by ISO, the UN and other organizations, kappa becomes "k".

In English, many people use a hybrid of the two systems. Because names such as Heracles, Cronos, Electra, Hecate and Socrates and places such as Crete, Cos, Corfu, Corinth, Macedonia and Attica are so well known under those spellings, they're always written that way in English.  Similarly, words such as *cycle*, *ecclesiastical* and *draconian* also come from Greek words where kappas have been romanized as "c".

However, modern names and places that weren't well-known in English before the modern transliteration scheme are usually spelled with "k"s. If you look at a map of Greece labelled in English, you'll see lots of these: Heraklion, Kythira, Mykonos, Lefkada, etc. Always Constantine the Great, but usually Konstantinos Karamanlis (though sometimes Constantine Caramanlis).

Comment: Wonderful answer.  Welcome to Mythology!

Comment: +1. I would offer one possible improvement: *c* for *κ* is not just vaguely "classical" but is a relic of transliteration of Greek ***into Latin**,* the alphabet for which lacks the apter letter *k.* Using *c* instead did not alter or distort pronunciation in classical Latin; it was only later Latin pronunciation that softened the *c* when followed by *e, i,* or *y.*

Comment: @BrianDonovan I added a little along those lines, though I didn't want to say too much as I know next to nothing about Latin.

Answer (score 5):

It's both. From my limited greek knowledge, κ is kappa, which translates to c or k. As a result, there's a Herakles and Heracles.

<s>(Though to be fair, Herakles looks a lot "older" and traditional than Heracles.)</s> As @DavidRicherby states, c is the traditional translation of kappa instead of k.

```
Ἡρ α|κ|λῆς
Hera|c|les
```

Stuff like this happens to Asklepios, I mean Asclepius

```
Ασ|κ|ληπιος
As|k|lepios
```

even Nike.

```
Νικη
Nicé
```

Note that it will always have the /k/ pronunciation.

Comment: Actually, "Herakles" is much more modern than "Heracles" in English, at least. Classical names are usually romanized with κ -> c (Crete, Corinth, Constantine, Electra, ...), whereas modern names usually use κ -> k.

Comment: is it? Most websites that list him use the c because it looks more like Hercules I guess.

Comment: No, most sites use the c because, traditionally, kappa has been romanized as c in English, not k. (Euclid, Hippocrates, Callicrates, Polycarp, Theocritus, Cleopatra, Pericles, Saint Cyril, ...)

Comment: @bleh I just realized, would you call Hercules Herkules?

Comment: @12944qwerty latin is a bit different, you use mostly the same characters (all the same characters if you don't count accents), and c is c and k is k.

Answer (score 3):

Great question!  Bleh is correct on the rendering in English (or other languages using the Latin alphabet) being dual, either a "c" or "k"

- **It is also [Hercules](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3DHercules) !**

This is the Latin form of the hero's name.

Comment: I just realized, would you call Hercules Herkules?

Comment: @12944qwerty It's not very common in English. But it's the standard spelling in Czech and many other languages that have more connection with the Greek origins. "Heracles" is usually spelled as "Héraklés", though most people simply call him "Herkules" (with proper inflection).

Answer (score -1):

Something you should know about english (i am born Crotian) languge its pronouncing bs 
many languges pronouncing  c like letter should use Herakles like greek pronouncing
try pronounce c - orn not c like k try c like c .....